# Get path / relative path of a folder and save its value in vscode

Tags: vscode-extensions

When you hover over a file or a folder within your workspace folder and right click, you have the option to 'Copy Path' and 'Copy Relative Path'.  Is there a  way with the vscode api that I can get these path values when a folder is right clicked on, and save this value in a string ?

I tried this:

```
vscode.commands.registerCommand('getPath', async (fileUri) => {
    console.log(fileUri);
});
```

This prints out an Object.  How can I access its fspath?  filrUri.fspath returns undefined.

Comment: Probably the URI is not a file path at all. In the debugger check what the content of the URI is. Maybe the URI was not constructed correctly?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my explanation.  I'm writing an extension and in this extension, I want to get the path of any workspace folder that I click on.  How do I get that value so I could use it in my code.  let x = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.fsPath gets the path from the first workspace folder but it needs a value within the array.  How can I get the path of any folder generally